# changing the font style of HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below HTML table.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsG7C/1/) link:

```
<table id="tabla" align="center" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Form View"></input></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Table view"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Classification1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Sic1:</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Sic Description1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Classification1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Sic1:</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Sic Description1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Classification1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Sic1:</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Sic Description1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Classification1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Sic1:</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Sic Description1:</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>Source:</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here each row has multiple tds. I want to change the label names to bold but not the value.
How can i do that?

Ex:

```
<td>Classification1:</td>
 <td>value</td>
```

Here `Classification1:` should be in bold and `value` should be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table is the wrong tool for this job!

This is for two reasons:

- Accessibility - vision impaired people using screen readers will have an easier time with your site.
- Search engines will be able to parse the site easier.

Use data definition lists:

```
 <dl>
      <dt>Classification1:</dt>
      <dd>value</dd>

      <dt>Source:</dt>
      <dd>value</dd>

      <dt>Sic1:</dt>
      <dd>Value</dd>

      <dt>Sic Description1:</dt>
      <dd>value</dd>

      <dt>Source:</dt>
      <dd>value</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dt, dd {margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;}
dt {font-weight:bold;}

dl>dd, dl>dt {float:left}
dl:after {clear:both;float:none;display:block;content:'';}
```

This is replicated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/netinept/GsG7C/9/

Answer (score 5):

Simple CSS solution:

```
#tabla tr td:nth-child(2n-1) {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight:bold
}
```

use this 
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sgbangale/GsG7C/5/)

Answer (score 0):

add  tag in front of the table name

```
      <td><b>classification</b></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS3 `:nth-child(odd)` or `:nth-child(even)` and fallback jQuery

**CSS3:**

```
tr td:nth-child(odd) {
         font-weight:bold;
       }
```

**Note**: nth-child doesn't support in IE.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr td:odd").css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/d94hA/)